# How can I get this vim functionality: find tag, go to file, if the file doesn't exist, sync it and then go there?

Tags: vim, try-catch, ctags

I have the following simple script. Where I want  to find a tag, and if multiple options are available, let me choose the correct version. If the file does not exist, I want to sync it (retrieve the file from a repository) and then go there.

I tried this as a test:

```
function! GoToTag ()
    try
        normal! g]
    catch
        "" sync out the file and try going there again ""
        echo v:exception
    endtry
endfunction

nnoremap <F7> :call GoToTag()<CR>
```

But I kept getting "Press ENTER or type command to continue" which blocks the user from responding to "Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):".

How do I get past this?

Comment: What do you mean by "sync it"?

Comment: Apologies. I meant to say that there is a repository that has all the files (such as git, svn, or perforce). So the source file that contains the definition may not be sync'd (checked out) locally, instead it needs to be retrieved from the repository first, then vim should jump to the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fix for the "Press Enter" issue was to use `exe 'tjump'` instead of `normal! g]`.

The rest of my solution is here in case others ever want to do the same thing:

```
function! GoToTag ()
    try
        let l:search_tag = expand('<cword>')    " Get the word under the cursor
        exe 'tjump' l:search_tag                " go to tag, list options if tag is in multiple locations
    catch /^Vim(tjump):E429:/                   " catch the missing file error if file doesn't exist (not synced)
        let l:exc = split(v:exception)          " Split the error message
        let l:filename = l:exc[2][1:-2]         " Extract the filename from the error message ([2]) and get rid of quotes ([1:-2])
        exe '!p4 sync' l:filename               " Sync the file
        call GoToTag()                          " Go to file again
    endtry
endfunction

nnoremap <F7> :call GoToTag()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `normal ^[` (insert the special character with `Ctrl-V`) or `execute "normal \<c-[>"`.

You could also use built-in functions to get the tag under the cursor, find the corresponding file (see `taglist`), retrieve it if necessary, and jump to the tag without further user interaction.

Comment: I don't think I I understand what you're saying. Adding 'normal ^[' just sent the cursor to the beginning of the line because of the ^. The "execute" suggestion also didn't do anything.
Regarding your second suggestion, I don't know how to get the user to give me his/her input when there's multiple files that contain that tag. Hence the g]

Comment: Vim shows `^[` (caret notation) for the special character inserted with `Ctrl-V ]` (see `:help i_CTRL-V`) and executes `:tag` using the tag under the cursor (see `:help CTRL-]`). That selects the first matching tag. For the second command, see `:help :normal`. If you want the user to choose a tag, `taglist` is still an option. If it returns several files, you can let the user choose one with the function `confirm`.

Comment: You can use the functions `shellescape` and `fnameescape` to escape the file names for the shell and Vim commands, respectively. In this way, problems caused by characters with special meaning (e.g. whitespace) in file names can be avoided.